# How to play audio with ImageButton and Exoplayer

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I am able to play audio using exoplayer inside and Activity 
My Activity that play the music. The activity also contains MediaSessionCompat.Callback that let for exemple notification to play that audio is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pascalito007/c2eb157dcb427b08213745b69ba7260a)

and also using App Widget.

```
PendingIntent playPausePendingIntent = MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context,
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, playPausePendingIntent);
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlay, icon);
```

My problem is how can I play ongoing music inside an ImageButton when I leave the activity?
Please find image below.

[image: How to handle the button at bottom right]

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for audio apps is having the player in a foreground services. This service runs independent from activities and hence the player survives when your activity is destroyed.

So to answer your question: your image button starts a foreground Service or sends a message to a service to play audi.

You may consider using a MediaBrowserService which is actually designed for this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html

The Anroid Universal Audio Player (UAMP) is a sample app which does just this: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/tree/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp